# How do I get elements out of a hyperoperator in the original order?

Tags: raku

I wanted to split a string into words and print each word on a separate line, so I tried the following:

```
"foo bar baz".words>>.say
```

However, the results weren't in order:

```
baz
foo
bar
```

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hyperoperators actually do return the results in order.  The problem with your code is that hyperops aren't looping constructs; they are list operators.  As such, their *execution* order is not guaranteed, and code that uses them as though it were is incorrect.  If you care about execution order, you should use a construct like `for` that guarantees it.

For example, this

```
my @a = "foo bar baz".words>>.split("a");
```

results in `@a` containing elements in the order you expect, regardless of the order in which each element was calculated:

```
foo b r b z
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me realize that I'd accidentally conflated execution order with return order.

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms Originally it would have done what you expected but for the wrong reasons. So this feature was modified to do the calculations in a slightly randomized order in Rakudo.

Answer (score 4):

To quote the [design docs](http://design.perl6.org/S03.html#line_4477),

> A hyperoperator is one of the ways that you can promise to the optimizer that your code is parallelizable.

Other ways to do so are `hyper` and `race`, which I don't think are implemented in Rakudo.

If you do care about order of evaluation, use a a `for` loop, `map` or `.map` instead of hyper operators, eg

```
"foo bar baz".words.map(&say)
```

The direct equivalent of your original code using the method form of `say` would read

```
"foo bar baz".words.map(*.say)
```

Answer (score 1):

When given a simple list, hyperoperators are allowed to process the elements in any order. This property facilitates parallelization.

If you simply want to act on each element of an array, in order, use `for`, instead:

```
for "foo bar baz".words { .say }
```

Which prints what you are looking for:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

---

#### UPDATE

I conflated execution and assignment. See darch's more correct (and accepted) answer.

Comment: I generally recommend waiting at least a day before answering your own questions

Comment: @BradGilbert When I find something interesting or surprising, I like to go ahead share it. I was surprised recently to realize that just below the "Post your Question" button is a checkbox "Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)". When you click on that checkbox, it opens up a box that allows you to enter an answer and post it at the same time.

Comment: [I have been recommending people wait before posting an answer to their own question since atleast August of 2009](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16936/1337), and [with a bit better explanation in October of 2010](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68738/1337).